# How to delete multiple text at the same time in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

Title says it all, how do I delete multiple text at the same time in Word 2010?

Example, right now my document is cluttered with

**Mediafire Link 
Code: Select All 
http://www.mediafire.com/?mdjnz2c5xzy**

I want to tidy up the document by removing the quoted text, thanks

Comment: Edit -> Replace All?

Answer (score 4):

Use Find and Replace (Ctrl+H) to replace "Mediafire Link Code: Select All http://www.mediafire.com/?mdjnz2c5xzy" with nothing (empty value). You can even get fancy add all wildcards and other options.